# C# call method from different class with 'args' as a parameter

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api, discord.net

I'm writing a Discord Bot (Discord.net) and I found myself requiring to access some data on a google sheet using their [API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2zej.png)s. Being that I thought it would be best to actually separate those two in two different class files I have tried summoning the **Main** method of the Google APIs into my program (*after having renamed it "**Sheets**"*) like this in my **Program.cs**:

```
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WoM_Balance_Bot
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GoogleAPI GSheet = new GoogleAPI();
            GSheet.Sheets();

            new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private DiscordSocketClient _client;

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _client.MessageReceived += CommandHandler;
            _client.Log += Log;

            var token = File.ReadAllText("bot-token.txt");

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await _client.StartAsync();

            // Block this task until the program is closed.
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }.......ecc
```

I tried writing the parameters to pass here [in these parentheses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2zej.png) like "***string***" and "***args***" but either I get the syntax wrong or I have a very wrong idea about what to pass exactly.

This is the actual content of **GoogleAPI.cs**, which is the other class file I created that has the Google Sheet APIs:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace WoM_Balance_Bot
{
    public class GoogleAPI
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        private static readonly string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };

        private static readonly string ApplicationName = "wombankrolls";

        public static void Sheets(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            Console.WriteLine("if you read this then it's good");

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define request parameters.
            String spreadsheetId = "16W56LWqt6wDaYAU5xNdTWCdaY_gkuQyl4CE1lPpUui4";
            String range = "Class Data!G163:I";
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                    service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

            // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
            // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
            ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;

            /*
            if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
                foreach (var row in values)
                {
                    // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row[0], row[4]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
            */
        }
    }
}
```

I have modified it from the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet) given by Google in a way that I thought it made sense but I still get in the end the same error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'args' of 'GoogleAPI.Sheets(string[])'

Comment: What is unclear about the message? You need to pass the `args` parameter. Although considering you don't use if in the `Sheets` function you might as well remove the parameter there instead.

Comment: why are you adding a `string[] args` parameter to your GoogleAPI.Sheets class method?  You don't ever use it.

Comment: I actually read that when dealing with APIs you should always keep the arguments open, my first idea was to remove it as-well

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if you do not use an argument, remove it.  C# helps enforce this paradigm by throwing a compiler error if your method expects an argument and you do not provide one, which is exactly what is happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the user "**David L**" wrote in the comments:
***As a general rule of thumb, if you do not use an argument, remove it. C# helps enforce this paradigm by throwing a compiler error if your method expects an argument and you do not provide one, which is exactly what is happening here.***

It was my bad as I was under the impression of the total opposite during an API implementation. I would like to always target a clean code as a result and keeping stuff that I will not use was my bad. Thank you David!